# If the distance between successive terms approaches 0, does the sequence converge?

Tags: real-analysis

Given $\lvert x_{n+1}-x_n\rvert$, I tried to show the sequence $\{x_n\}$ converged by showing $\lvert x_{n+1}-x_n\rvert$ converged to $0$ (i.e., the distance between successive terms of the sequence becomes infinitesimally small). My professor said this does not guarantee $\{x_n\}$ converges and that he wanted me to show the sequence is Cauchy. While I agree my proof does not directly show the sequence is Cauchy, I am uncertain why it does not show the sequence converges (which then implies the sequence is Cauchy).

Is there a counterexample that shows $\lvert x_{n+1}-x_n\rvert\to0$ as $n\to\infty$ does not guarantee convergence? Keep in mind this is only about the sequence itself and not a sum of its terms.

Comment: Consider $x_n = 1 + \frac{1}{2} + \ldots + \frac{1}{n}.$

Comment: There are counterexamples even if you require that $|x_n|<M$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $x_n=\sqrt n$. Then $x_{n+1}-x_n\to 0$ but $x_n\to\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

$x_1=1$ and $x_{n}=x_{n-1}+1/n$ for $n\geq2$ would be a counterexample.